# Node: Process a 2D array of promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, bluebird

I have a 2D array (2 X n) of promises and I want first to process all the promises in Row 1 and then all the promises in Row 2.

In other words, I want to chain one group of promises after another group of promises completes its execution.

How can I achieve this?

I tried the following but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
 Promise.resolve()
    .then(createPromises)//generates topPromises= [ [p1, p2, p3], [p4,p5,p6]]
    .then(function(topPromises){
      Promise.all(topPromises[0])
      .then(Promise.all[topPromises[1])
    })
```

Comment: What is the final data structure or output you're looking for ?

Comment: The final data structure depends on the order of execution. E.g., adding data in a DB where Stores (promises p1--p3) should be added before Items (promises p4--p6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull this off using a little bit of pseudo-recursion.

Essentially, you have a function which completes one group of promises. Once it completes, you call that same function again but with the next group.

```js
let promiseCount = 1;
function create() {
  let n = promiseCount++;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(n);
      resolve();
    }, 500 * n);
  });
}

let groups = [
  [create(), create(), create()],
  [create(), create(), create()],
  [create(), create(), create()]
];

(function runGroup(i) {
  if (i < groups.length) {
    Promise.all(groups[i])
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Group', i + 1, 'complete');
        runGroup(i + 1);
      });
  }
})(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I'm trying to achieve. Would this work if other promises are invoked within the create function?

Comment: @STiGMa Sure, no problems there.

Comment: thanks for the help. I solved the issue following your example.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `return`, and you pass a `Promise` instead of `function` in one of `.then`'s

```
 Promise.resolve()
.then(createPromises)//generates topPromises= [ [p1, p2, p3], [p4,p5,p6]]
.then(function(topPromises){
  return Promise.all(topPromises[0])
  .then(() => Promise.all[topPromises[1]))
})
```

I don't know exactly what you need, but probably your code may looks like that:

```
cratePromises().reduce((topPromise, nestedPromises) => {
  return topPromise.then(data => {
    // data is empty array on first iteration and array of nestedPromises values on next iterations
    return Promise.all(nestedPromises)
  })
}, Promise.resolve([]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that the example is incomplete (for simplicity). Could you please give some explanation for your code? I don't have much experience with Node.

Comment: @STiGMa Actually this code is not node-specific, it's plain JavaScript.
I'm using `reduce` function for build promise chain from nested array of promises.
It can be replaced to `.forEach` method or even `for` operator like that:
  

```let topPromise = Promise.resolve()

cratePromises().forEach(nestedPromises => {
  topPromise = topPromise.then(data => {
    return Promise.all(nestedPromises)
  })
})```


Sorry, there was (and probably still exists) some stupid errors in my code samples like missed `()` after `createPromises`